# How to enforce using cloudpickle in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle

It seems like spark has trouble with pickling/unpickling on the remote workers. Is there a way to tell it to use cloudpickle?

Comment: This question would make more sense if you provide context. Spark does use cloudpickle to serialize closure, and it is not configurable, so it is likely you've misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, if cloudpickle is always on then I am indeed chasing the wrong angle. 

Basically, wrapped (decorated) functions tend to fail as well as certain kinds of functions in the same module.

I think these are multiple different problems with pickling so will post elsewhere when I have good examples.

Comment: AFAIK only data (RDD) serializer is configurable. In general there are a few sources of serialization issues with closures - objects using native extensions (typically with direct memory access or memory mapping, but not limited to these), objects which are intentionally not serializable (thread locks and connections for example) and object referencing local classes (as `cloudpickle`, same as pickle, doesn't serialize class definitions). If you have something sharable (tracebacks maybe) these might give us some hints.

Comment: @mathtick Do you have code samples?

Comment: @chhantyal This was a long time ago, I think I remember that the code forks depending on what kind of setup you are using (standalone, yarn, mesos) etc. I think I got around this unpickling error by setting the PYTHONPATH in the sparkContext configuration. Sorry can't remember more detail.

Comment: not sure if this should be closed or what. feel free to suggest.